# Using IF function in EXCEL to search a specific word in list

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Is there a way to search for a specific word in a list. An example being a row where "`5,Carbamidomethyl[C]#0;30,Oxidation[M]#0`" is shown. We want EXCEL to generate TRUE if they find "`Carbamidomethyl`" in that list and FALSE if not, can this be done with IF function or is there any other suggestions so how the problem can be tackled?

ps I know this can be done in other programming languages but Excel I have not found a solution in.

Comment: If that text is in one cell, then use ISNUMBER, and FIND or SEARCH. If you're looking in a row (i..e multiple cells), you can use COUNTIF with wildcards `*`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen the text is in one cell as you mentioned, but it will be done in a long list. Furthermore, the FIND or SEARCH function moreso generates a location where the word is located and an error if it is not there. Which could solve the problem in some ways, but there is no easier function that generates a true or false answer?

Comment: That's why you use FIND or SEARCH together with ISNUMBER. ISNUMBER returns TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: ok so you mean i first create a FIND or SEARCH function and thereafter use ISNUMBER? Gottcha thanks

Comment: E.g. `=ISNUMBER(FIND("Carbamidomethyl",A1))`. Or `=COUNTIF(A1,"*Carbamidomethyl*")>0`.